# Performing ctrl+c without interupting console program

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to use pyautogui to automate a simple copying task on windows. It should move the mouse to point x,y, perform ctrl+c to copy some content, move the mouse to x1,y2 and press ctrl+v.

Here is my code:

```
pyautogui.moveTo(330, 450)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
pyautogui.moveTo(530, 450)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
```

Problem: The program interrupts if you perform ctrl+c as any console program does and the last two lines are not executed.

Answer (score 0):

try using('ctrl', 'Insert') instead. It should copy the text without closing the programme.